# paypal plus integration - redirect to authorize payment not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to understand the paypal plus api ([Integration guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf)). At the moment, I do all requests with the chrome extension dhc. I'm able to create a payment resource. The next step is the payment wall, which I get with the following code (according the Integration Guide, page 15):

```
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pay Pal Plus Test</title>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
        "approvalUrl": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-3R842713T4893315T",
        "placeholder": "ppplus",
        "mode": "sandbox",
        "country": "DE"
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ppplus"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The approvalUrl is copied from my payment resource. When I open this html-file and click on continue, nothing happens. Furthermore, there is no exception or error-message on the console. As far as I understand, I should be redirected to authorize the payment (Integration Guide, page 21).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Is there somewhere a working example?

Thank you very much

Michael